# How to use local application script with spark-submit on mesos/docker?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, mesos, spark-submit

I'm using `spark-submit` in "cluster" mode with a Python script against a Spark cluster running on Mesos, and a custom Docker image for the executor set in `spark.mesos.executor.docker.image`.

My script file is already baked into the Docker image (let's say at path `/app/script.py`), so I don't want to use spark-submit's feature to download the script via HTTP before executing.

Per https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management this seems possible by specifying the application script as a `local:` URL, e.g. `spark-submit [...options...] local:/app/script.py`. However this didn't work, I'm seeing errors like the following on Mesos (stderr of the spark driver task, scheduled by the spark-dispatcher framework):

```
I0727 20:31:50.164263  9207 fetcher.cpp:533] Fetcher Info: {"cache_directory":"\/tmp\/mesos\/fetch\/root","items":[{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"cache":false,"extract":true,"value":"\/app\/script.py"}}],"sandbox_directory":"\/data\/mesos\/slaves\/GUID\/frameworks\/GUID\/executors\/driver-TIMESTAMP\/runs\/GUID","user":"root"}
I0727 20:31:50.170289  9207 fetcher.cpp:444] Fetching URI '/app/script.py'
I0727 20:31:50.170361  9207 fetcher.cpp:285] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
I0727 20:31:50.170413  9207 fetcher.cpp:222] Fetching URI '/app/script.py'
cp: cannot stat ‘/app/script.py’: No such file or directory
E0727 20:31:50.174051  9207 fetcher.cpp:579] EXIT with status 1: Failed to fetch '/app/script.py': Failed to copy '/app/script.py': exited with status 1
s 1
```

After browsing through https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html, my guess is that the `local:` path is interpreted by a "MesosClusterDispatcher", which is a daemon that spins up a container for the Spark driver process (using my custom spark executor Docker image). Since this dispatcher doesn't itself run in the custom Docker image/container, it can't find the file.

Is there any other way to tell spark-submit to *not* download the application script and just use the script already present in the Docker image?

Comment: Did you get any break through?